# Unity GetKeyDown seems to register two times

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was working on an interactable button script for a 3D game in unity, when I noticed that if I pressed the interact button(e) for a bit longer the script ran twice despite having used the "GetKeyDown" command which should only run for one frame. I have two instances of those buttons, so I created a "buttonId" variable to differentiate each of them. However, when I looked at the console I saw that both messages came from the same button at the exact same time. If I release the button fast enough(meaning I barely tap it), the script only runs once and everything works just fine. This said, I have no idea what's wrong.

```
public float radius = 3;

public int buttonId = 0;
//changed in editor for every instance of the script

void Update()
{
    Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, radius);
    //look for colliders in a radius

    for (int i = 0; i < hitColliders.Length; i++)
    {
        if (hitColliders[i].CompareTag("Player"))
        //checks if the collider it's looking at is the player's collider
        {
            // *other stuff*

            if (Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
            //checks whether it's the frame where e was pressed or not 
            {
                Debug.Log("E pressed\nButton ID: " + buttonId);
                // *do stuff*
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Console feed:

> "E pressed  Button ID: 1 UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
> ButtonScript:Update() (at Assets/Scripts/ButtonScript.cs:90)"

this, but two times

unity version: "Unity 2019.3.14f1 Personal <DX11>"

Comment: Could be because you're checking inside of a for loop. Add `break;` right after the `Debug.Log`.

Comment: Yes, it would've solved the problem since I had 2 objects with the tag "player" meaning the script ran for both of them

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is a bit backwards; you're doing:

> Every frame, scan for close Colliders and if the Player clicks E, do something for each of them

but should be doing:

> Every frame, check if Player clicks E and if someone is close, do something

Given the code supplied, it could probably be refactored to something like:

```cs
Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, radius);

var playerCollided = hitColliders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CompareTag("Player")) != null;

if (playerCollided)
{
    // *other stuff*
}


if (playerCollided && Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
{
    Debug.Log("E pressed\nButton ID: " + buttonId);
}
```

Comment: oh, thank you! I didn't know about the FirstOrDefault method, so I don't really understand it, but I'll look into it!

Comment: It is more efficent than my code since it doesn't have to loop through the whole array, and it only runs the code for one(the first) object, wich means it would've solved my problem(since the problem was that there was a child to the og object with the "player" tag making two objects with that tag and it ran the code once for each of them). Again, thank you very much!

Comment: but it registered 4 times now

Comment: Haha, okay. Have you by any chance added the script to 4 different GameObjects?

Comment: No, but I managed to solve the problem, thank you for your time and sorry that it didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

My bad, the player had two objects on it with the "player" tag so the script ran for both of them. I already fixed it